# sql last day date function

Tags: sql

I have table like below, and I need to choose only the data for end day of each month. What proper query should I use ? I need also automated it, and with each subsequent montt the last day each month needs to be choose automaticly.

```
date_list
date=20201231
date=20211220
date=20201130
date=20201115
date=20201030
date=20201009
.
.
.
.
 thanks,
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS (database management system)?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: T-sql is my rdbms

Comment: Does anyone has any idea how to do this?